# How do I tell Maven to package the file compared to my profiles

Tags: java, maven

i have this structure in my `maven` project

```
src
|
|_java
|_resources
|_webapp
  |
  |_addin
    |
    |_fckconfig.dev.js
    |_fckconfig.js
    |_fckconfig.prod.js
```

***my pom.xml:***

```
<properties>
        <webXmlfolder>default</webXmlfolder>
        <profileVersion>defaultVersion</profileVersion>
        <majorVersion>2</majorVersion>
        <minorVersion>50.3-0</minorVersion>
    </properties>

    <profiles>
        <profile>
            <id>dev</id>
            <properties>
                <profileVersion>DEV</profileVersion>
                <webXmlfolder>dev</webXmlfolder>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>preprod</id>
            <properties>
                <profileVersion>PREPROD</profileVersion>
                <webXmlfolder>preprod</webXmlfolder>
            </properties>
        </profile>

        <profile>
            <id>prod</id>
            <properties>
                <profileVersion>PROD</profileVersion>
                <webXmlfolder>prod</webXmlfolder>
            </properties>
        </profile>
    </profiles>

    <!-- FIN Profiles -->

    <build>
        <finalName>${project.artifactId}-${project.version}</finalName>
        <resources>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/resources/</directory>
                <filtering>true</filtering>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/*.${webXmlfolder}.*</include>
                </includes>
            </resource>
            <resource>
                <directory>src/main/webapp/addin</directory> 
                <filtering>true</filtering> 
                <includes> 
                    <include>/addin/*.${webXmlfolder}.*</include> 
                </includes> 
            </resource>
        </resources>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-resources-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.4</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>copy-web.xml</id>
                        <phase>package</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy-resources</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <overwrite>true</overwrite>
                            <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}-${project.version}/WEB-INF</outputDirectory>
                            <resources>
                                <resource>
                                    <directory>src/main/config/${webXmlfolder}/WEB-INF</directory>
                                    <filtering>true</filtering>
                                </resource>
                            </resources>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
```

when i execute `mvn clean install -P prod` i want to have just:

```
src
|
|_java
|_resources
|_webapp
  |
  |_addin
    |
    |_fckconfig.prod.js
```

but there is nothing going on I always file now, why?

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Aren't you missing a `main` folder in your project structure? It is `src/java` in your diagram. Also, the result will be inside target in the WAR so you're looking at the wrong directory.

Comment: In your project packaging= war?

Comment: @lquitada yes packaging= war

Comment: @Tunaki i have edit my post

Comment: As I said, you not looking in the right directory. You should look inside the generated WAR.

Comment: @Tunaki i look in the war yes

Comment: That's not what your text is saying.

Comment: @Tunaki i look in the snapshot which was generating. what's wrong ?

Answer (score 0):

As exaplained for [maven war plugin](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/usage.html) , src/main/webapp is default folder for web application source. So, all file in src/main/webapp will be automatically added to war. Try to move addin folder outside src/main/webapp.
If you couldn't move folder, you need to work with 'exclude' tags as exaplained [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-war-plugin/examples/adding-filtering-webresources.html).

Comment: the pb is when i open my war the folder `addin`is present , i post picture for explain

Comment: all file in src/main/webapp will be ever added to final war. To exclude some directory/files you need to configure maven-war plugin as explained in last link.

Comment: so why `addin`folder is present ?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you take advance of the `maven-war-plugin` to configure the contents of your WAR file based upon your profiles:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.6</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>default-war</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>war</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <webXml>src/main/config/${webXmlfolder}/WEB-INF/web.xml</webXml>
                        <warSourceIncludes>*.*</warSourceIncludes>
                        <warSourceIncludes>addin/*.${webXmlfolder}.js</warSourceIncludes>
                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

By the way, I notice you have one possible incompatibility about the copy-web.xml plugin if you execute it at the `package` phase, because the war plugin always executes in that same phase, too:

- Either move the copy-web.xml to an early phase.
- Either take advance of the `<webxml>` node from the `maven-war-plugin`, as I have included in my scriptlet... But assuming your `web.xml` files do not need to be filtered. (Do they?)